# Serialize a Trie

Tags: c, memory-management

I created a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) to store few millions of words.

```
typedef struct trie
{
    struct trie* c[38];
    unsigned int occ;
} trie_t;
```

occ is just a number that store the number of occurence of the words. If 0 : the node isn't a word.
c[38] is for : 26 letters + 10 number + '_' + '.'

I want to serialize it so I can mmap it back into memory without having to build it each time.
The problem is I used malloc to create the Trie so all the memory isn't contigous.

I'd like to force the memory the Trie is created in to be contigous so I can replace pointers by offset and serialize the whole structure.

Is this the right way to go ?
Is it even possible with malloc or should I build my own memory allocator to do this ?

Comment: So is this trie static once built -- you don't update it?

Comment: yes. No update. The Trie is created from a list of words that will never change.

Comment: Then just build it.  Understand that you will likely "bend" some C rules and have to rely on dreaded "undocumented behavior" to do the addressing, but no biggie.

Comment: You can serialize each node, and give them a serial number, then when you unserialize it you can reconnect it based on serial number...

Comment: Do consider the order in which you build it, to optimize "locality" when walking through the structure.

Comment: @HotLicks You don't need any of that nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate a single array of structs and use them in sequence. In case you don't know the total size of structs you will need, then you realloc the array.

The final result is an contiguous array of trie structs that point all over.

Comment: Hmmm...What you mean is I just allocate a big array, make a "my_malloc(size)" that has a static int "offset" poiting to where I am in this array and do :  return array[offset]; offset+=size;
(+the realloc stuff), right ?

Comment: Something like that if you decide to use a function. You have two vars total_size and current_position, and realloc when you reach total_size. Since you have an array of structs you would increment by 1 not by size.

Comment: "Since you have an array of structs you would increment by 1 not by size" : I always make this mistake :)